# Java jar-Archive tool - Set path for folder with content

Tags: command, cmd, java, prompt

When I use this command:

`echo C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin`

`jar -cf C:\file\file.jar C:\data\`

in the CMD for the jar-Archive tool, it creates the .jar called "file.jar" in `C:\file\`, but it doesn't add the files from the folder `C:\data`, it creates an archive with the folder `C: -> data -> files` (in this case text.txt). How can I set the path for the folder with the content in it? I only want the files in the folder `C:\data\` in my archive. How can I do this?

Thanks, **DigitalClark**.

*btw.:* Is there any way to do this without JDK? Is there another tool? I don't want the users to install JDK to use just a little program...

Answer (score 1):

This should work, maybe you have to omit the last slash:

> jar -cf C:\file\file.jar C:\data

Concerning your last question: [Java JDK .jar archive tool alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873221/java-jdk-jar-archive-tool-alternative)

Yes, you can use any program that can create zip archives. Your probably have to rename them from *.zip to *.jar

Comment: Thank you :-)! But then I can't execute the .jar files :-/... It throws me an error...

Comment: It says `Invalid or corrupt jarfile`. I also tried different compression methods.

Comment: ** With 7zip command line. What I try to do is to extract an already existing .jar-File, add some files to it and then recompile it. That works, but I can't run it then. It throws me that error.

Comment: Are you creatimg a zip file or is it a 7zip with the wrong extension?