# Java JDK .jar archive tool alternative

Tags: jar, zip, cmd, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java jar-Archive tool - Set path for folder with content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872936/java-jar-archive-tool-set-path-for-folder-with-content)

Is there any alternative to JDK's jar.exe (for archiving and creating .jar-Files) for the CMD? I want to archive .jar-Files without having the user to install JDK before using my little program. 7zip command line doesn't work with .jar-Files...

Thank you,
**DigitalClark**.

Comment: Don't flood StackOverflow with the same question again and again. If your question isn't answered, then think about making it clearer, edit it, and wait for answers.

Answer (score 2):

A jar file is a zip file with a `.jar` file extension. Any zip tool will do.

Comment: Well, 7zip command line won't work :-/... It says the archive-file is not supported... Can I execute it after editing it anyway?

Comment: Are you telling me that 7zip can't create zip files? If it can, then create one, and rename the created file.zip to file.jar.

Comment: No, 7zip can create zip files... I tried this. When I wanted to execute the .jar then, it said that JVM can't execute it because the file is damaged or something...

Comment: That said: users don't need a JDK to run a jar file. They need a JRE. They don't need to create or extract jars. Only to run them.